# How to create a function that returns a SETOF type in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, set, postgresql-9.5

How do I go about creating a function that returns a SETOF type in postgresql? All my attempts are getting me the following error:

> SQL function cannot return shell type...

Below is the query I am trying to run:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.assignment_scores(
    skuunit_groupset_uid text,
    userrole_uid text,
    periodid integer,
    dataset_uid text)
  RETURNS SETOF score_in_assignment AS
$BODY$

    SELECT DISTINCT sku.uid stu_uid,
    EXTRACT(DAY FROM cdsr.date - p.enddate)::int AS delay,
    skudistrict.name AS skuunit_parent_name,
    sku.name AS skuunit_group_name,
    sku.uid AS oskuunit_group_uid,
    cdsr.storedby AS username,
    ui.phonenumber
    FROM completedatasetregistration cdsr
    INNER JOIN period p ON cdsr.periodid = p.periodid
    INNER JOIN dataset ds ON cdsr.datasetid = ds.datasetid
    INNER JOIN skuunit skuvillage ON cdsr.sourceid = skuvillage.skuunitid
    INNER JOIN _skuunitstructure ous ON cdsr.sourceid = ous.skuunitid
    INNER JOIN organisationunit oudistrict ON oudistrict.organisationunitid =           `   ous.idlevel3`
    INNER JOIN skugroupmembers ougm ON ougm.skuunitid = oudistrict.skuunitid
    INNER JOIN orgunitgroup oug ON oug.orgunitgroupid = ougm.skuunitgroupid 
    INNER JOIN skuunitgroupsetmembers ougsm ON ougsm.skuunitgroupid = `   `     oug.orgunitgroupid
    INNER JOIN orgunitgroupset ougs ON ougs.orgunitgroupsetid = `         ougsm.orgunitgroupsetid` 
    AND ougs.uid = $1
    INNER JOIN users u ON cdsr.storedby = u.username
    INNER JOIN userinfo ui ON u.userid = ui.userinfoid
    INNER JOIN userrolemembers urm ON u.userid = urm.userid
    INNER JOIN userrole ur ON urm.userroleid = ur.userroleid 
    AND ur.uid = $2 
    WHERE p.periodid = $3 --lock to a single period
    AND ds.uid = $4 --lock to a single dataset
    AND EXTRACT(DAY FROM cdsr.date - p.enddate) < DATE_PART('days',    `  DATE_TRUNC('month', p.startdate) + '1 MONTH'::INTERVAL - DATE_TRUNC('month', p.startdate)) AND EXTRACT(DAY FROM cdsr.date - p.enddate) >= 0 ;

$BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE
```

I do not know if a similar question has already been asked and solved. If it has, please point me to it.

Comment: What is the definition of `score_in_assignment`. Also: did you try a PL/pgSQL function?

Comment: Have you tried returning `SETOF record` instead of `SETOF score_in_assignment`?

Comment: Looks like you created `score_in_assignment` as a shell type. Run your `CREATE TYPE` statement again, but this time, give it a field list...

Answer (score 0):

*[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77944893/how-to-create-the-value-of-setof-sometype-type-by-hand-in-postgresql/77957084#77957084) explains how to create `SETOF <sometype>` type by hand in detail.

For example, you can create `my_func()` which returns `SETOF INT` type as shown below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS SETOF INT
AS $$
VALUES (1), (2), (3);
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Then, calling `my_func()` returns 3 rows as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT my_func();
 my_func
---------
       1
       2
       3
(3 rows)
```

And, you can create `my_func()` which returns `SETOF TEXT` type as shown below. *You can replace `TEXT` with `VARCHAR`:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS SETOF TEXT
AS $$
VALUES ('John'), ('David'), ('Robert');
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Then, calling `my_func()` returns 3 rows as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT my_func();
 my_func
---------
 John
 David
 Robert
(3 rows)
```

And, you can create `my_func()` which returns `SETOF RECORD` type as shown below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS SETOF RECORD
AS $$
VALUES ('John','Smith'), ('David','Miller');
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Then, calling `my_func()` returns 2 rows as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT my_func();
    my_func
----------------
 (John,Smith)
 (David,Miller)
(2 rows)
```