# How to create the value of `SETOF <sometype>` type by hand in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, types, set

PostgreSQL has `SETOF <sometype>` type according to [the doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING-RETURN-NEXT) and `SETOF <sometype>` type is used in a function as shown below:

```sql
                               -- ↓ ↓ ↓ Here ↓ ↓ ↓                         
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS SETOF <sometype>
...
```

Now, I want to create the value of `SETOF <sometype>` type by hand like we can create an array and create a row with `ROW()` by hand as shown below:

```sql
SELECT ARRAY[1,2,3]::INT[]; -- {1,2,3}
```

```sql
SELECT ROW(1,'John',27); -- (1,John,27)
```

So, how can I create the value of `SETOF <sometype>` type by hand?

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to use a `VALUES` statement:

```
VALUES ('someval'::sometype),
       ('otherval'::sometype),
       ...;
```

You can use such a statement as a subquery. Another way is to unnest an array:

```
unnest('{someval,otherval}'::sometype[])
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can create the value of `SETOF INT` type as shown below:

```sql
VALUES (1), (2), (3);
```

```sql
SELECT unnest(ARRAY[1,2,3]);
```

```sql
SELECT generate_series(1,3);
```

```sql
SELECT generate_subscripts(ARRAY['apple','orange','banana'], 1);
```

And, you can create the value of `SETOF TEXT` type as shown below:

```sql
VALUES ('John'), ('David'), ('Robert');
```

```sql
SELECT unnest(ARRAY['John','David','Robert']);
```

And, you can create the value of `SETOF RECORD` type as shown below:

```sql
VALUES ('John','Smith'), ('David','Miller');
```

```sql
SELECT unnest(ARRAY[ROW('John','Smith'),ROW('David','Miller')]);
```

And, you can create the value of `SETOF INT[]` type as shown below:

```sql
VALUES (ARRAY[1,2,3]), (ARRAY[4,5,6]);
```

And, you can create the value of `SETOF TEXT[]` type as shown below:

```sql
VALUES (ARRAY['John','David']), (ARRAY['Robert','Mark']);
```

*Memos:

- [The doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html) explains `unnest()`.
- [The doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html) explains `generate_series()` and `generate_subscripts()`.
- You cannot create the value of `SETOF RECORD[]` type because `SETOF RECORD[]` type doesn't exist in PostgreSQL so if you use `SETOF RECORD[]` type, there is error. *`RECORD[]` itself doesn't exist in PostgreSQL so if you use `RECORD[]`, there is [the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77969232/declaring-a-record-variable-gets-variable-has-pseudo-type-record-e).
- [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50835783/input-of-anonymous-composite-types-is-not-implemented-postgresql#77952926) explains how to create the array of rows.
- [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11831555/get-nth-element-of-an-array-that-returns-from-string-to-array-function/#77723802) explains how to create and use the 1D array with `INT[]` in detail.
- [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71406989/declare-an-array-in-postgresql#77723752) explains how to create and use the 1D(one-dimensional) array with `VARCHAR[]` in detail.